# How to use .bind() to tie down the value of this?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding

It's probably a dumb question but what pattern can i use in the following situation to use **bind** method to tie down the value of **this** inside a method in the code below.

```
'use strict';

exports.service = function() {
    this.colors = [];
    this.years = [];
    this.trims = [];
    var scope = this;

    this.setColors = function(colorsArr) {
        scope.colors = colorsArr;
    };

    this.setYears = function(yearsArr) {
        scope.years = yearsArr;
    };

    this.getVehicleDetails = function() {
        return {
            colors: scope.colors,
            years: scope.years
        };
    };

    this.getTrims = function() {
        return trims;
    };
};
```

Comment: In my opinion what you're doing with the variable seems cleaner, assuming everything works and you just want to use `bind` for some reason? Also note that `this` depends on the the way the function is called, not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the `bind` to all the methods. Then you can use `this` inside all the inner methods.

```
'use strict';

exports.service = function() {
    this.colors = [];
    this.years = [];
    this.trims = [];

    this.setColors = function(colorsArr) {
        this.colors = colorsArr; // Use this here
    }.bind(this); // Change of context

    this.setYears = function(yearsArr) {
        this.years = yearsArr; // Use this here
    }.bind(this); // Change of context

    this.getVehicleDetails = function() {
        return {
            colors: this.colors, // Use this here
            years: this.years // Use this here
        };
    }.bind(this); // Change of context

    this.getTrims = function() {
        return this.trims; // Use this here
    }.bind(this); // Change of context
};
```